# Why are Pickle files in Pickle protocol 4 twice as large as those in protocol 3 without having any gains in speed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am testing Python 3.4, and I noticed that the pickle module has a new protocol. Therefore, I benchmark 2 protocols.

```
def test1():
    pickle3=open("pickle3","wb")
    for i in range(1000000):
        pickle.dump(i,pickle3,3)
    pickle3.close()
    pickle3=open("pickle3","rb")
    for i in range(1000000):
        pickle.load(pickle3)

def test2():
    pickle4=open("pickle4","wb")
    for i in range(1000000):
        pickle.dump(i, pickle4,4)
    pickle3.close()
    pickle4=open("pickle4","rb")
    for i in range(1000000):
        pickle.load(pickle4)
```

test1 mark: 2000007 function calls in 6.473 seconds

test2 mark: 2000007 function calls in 6.740 seconds

Protocol 4 is slightly slower than Protocol 3. This kind of difference can be ignored. However, the hard disk usage is really different.

pickle3 uses 7,868,672 bytes.

pickle4 uses 16,868,672 bytes.

That's no reason. I continue to dig out. After read [PEP3154](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3154/), I roughly understand the protocol.

for Tuple(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) of Protocol 3

```
    0: \x80 PROTO      3
    2: (    MARK
    3: K        BININT1    1
    5: K        BININT1    2
    7: K        BININT1    3
    9: K        BININT1    4
   11: K        BININT1    5
   13: K        BININT1    6
   15: K        BININT1    7
   17: t        TUPLE      (MARK at 2)
   18: q    BINPUT     0
   20: .    STOP
```

for Tuple(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) of Protocol 4

```
    0: \x80 PROTO      4
    2: \x95 FRAME      18
   11: (    MARK
   12: K        BININT1    1
   14: K        BININT1    2
   16: K        BININT1    3
   18: K        BININT1    4
   20: K        BININT1    5
   22: K        BININT1    6
   24: K        BININT1    7
   26: t        TUPLE      (MARK at 11)
   27: \x94 MEMOIZE
   28: .    STOP
```

The unpickler of protocol 3 cannot know the length of the data until it reads to position 17.

For protocol 4, from position 2 to postion 18, there is a heading which shows the length.

**However, I still do not get it why I pay the price (almost double the hard disk usage in a extreme situation) but the speed is the same or potentially slower?**

Comment: Isn't it clear from the PEP why the approach was taken? This is about *read performance*, especially for more complex structures with many small values contained. Your performance test doesn't take that into account; you write *and* read.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The PEP is really clear. I thought new protocol means free optimization. Now I know I was wrong. BTW, is it better that combine protocol 3 and protocol 4?

Comment: And just to make it more obvious: you are writing *individual small pickles*, which means you are completely circumventing the framing advantages here. If you wrote *one* pickle with a list of integers, you'd be able to take advantage of the framing, but you are just hobbling the format now.

Comment: There is a bug in your code. In the pickle4 case you are still closing pickle3 not pickle4.

Answer (score 2):

You are pickling ints. There is no gain in knowing the size of the structure in advance for such a simple datatype. For more complex structures, knowing the frame size is a huge gain in processing speed. Besides, protocol 4 lifts many restrictions for 64bit systems.