# Can I pickle "self" of a python class?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I intend to save all my class variables at the current stage and load them later for replicating the same work. I tried to pickle all the object instance of the class but I guess since I created another sub object in the target object, it cannot pickle. My another solution is to pickle objects "self" to reload all the class wide variables for later use. Is it viable through pickle or what do you suggest?

For instance I have

```
class A:
...

class B:
...
def __init__():
    self.A_ins = A
    self.var1 = ...
    self.var2 = ...

b = B()
f = open(file_name,'wb')
pickle.dump(b,f)
```

This is the error I got, if I try to pickle directly

```
TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

In this example I try to save Class B object and reload it later. If it is not possible because of sub object A_ins, I propose to pickle self of class B object and reload it.

Comment: how exactly have you tried to use `pickle` in the above code plz? what is the error message / unexpected behaviour you got?

Comment: So... what was the solution? Please mark the answer that gave you the solution if any. And if not just comment why not.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you're setting `self.A_ins` to the class A, not to an instance of class A. That could be your problem -- you're trying to pickle the `__init__()` method of A.

Try changing `self.A_ins = A` to `self.A_ins = A()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pickle that with `pickle`, however if you use `dill`, this should not be a problem.  `dill` should be able to pickle `B` regardless if have an instance of `A` or the class object `A` (as you have above).

```
Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 10 2014, 21:37:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...   pass
... 
>>> class B:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.A_ins = A 
...     self.var1 = 1
...     self.var2 = 2
... 
>>> b = B()
>>>   
>>> import dill
>>> dill.dumps(b)
b'\x80\x03cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x04\x00\x00\x00typeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04X\x01\x00\x00\x00Bq\x05h\x01X\x06\x00\x00\x00objectq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(X\r\x00\x00\x00__slotnames__q\x0b]q\x0cX\n\x00\x00\x00__module__q\rX\x08\x00\x00\x00__main__q\x0eX\x08\x00\x00\x00__init__q\x0fcdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x10(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x11C\xb0c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x1f\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00|\x00\x00_\x01\x00d\x01\x00|\x00\x00_\x02\x00d\x02\x00|\x00\x00_\x03\x00d\x00\x00S(\x03\x00\x00\x00Ni\x01\x00\x00\x00i\x02\x00\x00\x00(\x04\x00\x00\x00u\x01\x00\x00\x00Au\x05\x00\x00\x00A_insu\x04\x00\x00\x00var1u\x04\x00\x00\x00var2(\x01\x00\x00\x00u\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00u\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>u\x08\x00\x00\x00__init__\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\t\x01\t\x01q\x12\x85q\x13Rq\x14c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0fNN}q\x15tq\x16Rq\x17X\x07\x00\x00\x00__doc__q\x18Nutq\x19Rq\x1a)\x81q\x1b}q\x1c(X\x05\x00\x00\x00A_insq\x1dh\x00(h\x04X\x01\x00\x00\x00Aq\x1eh\x08\x85q\x1f}q (h\x18Nh\rh\x0eutq!Rq"X\x04\x00\x00\x00var2q#K\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00var1q$K\x01ub.'
>>> 
>>> _b = dill.loads(dill.dumps(b))
>>> _b.A_ins 
<class '__main__.A'>
>>>
```

Comment: The above will pickle your class regardless of you using python 2 or python 3. `dill` can pickle both old and new style classes, as well.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709800/how-to-pickle-yourself/25128214#25128214

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `Python2`, you have `classic classes`, which are unpickelable. Try to inherit from object, i.e. replace `class A:` with `class A(object):`.

If you are on `Python3` I guess you have a different problem, since newstyle is the default. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle

### EDIT:

Do not assume OP uses `Python2`

Comment: Where does the OP say it's Python2?

Comment: I must have imagined it